# how to convert date in excel to sql format using php?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I read the date from excel using php and convert to sql format using following code

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($cell));
```

but after convertion the date is not correct.
how to solve this problem?

Comment: what is your $cell output and what is expecting?

Comment: what is the format of the date in `$cell`? in terms of `dd-mm-yyy` etc...

Comment: sample value from `$cell` needed

Comment: format of $cell is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Format of the cell is meaningless; it's the value in the cell that's important, and that should be an Excel serialized date/time value

Comment: the value in cell is 1/3/1994

Comment: If the value in the cell is 1/3/1994, then it's a simple string, not a date, so there is no format setting, and you shouldn't be having any problems..... but it's more likely to be a timestamp value like 34394.0 that's formatted using a date format mask.... you can check by setting the format mask for the cell to "number"

Comment: @MarkBaker yeah i got the value 34394 for 1/3/1994 then how i convert this to the format Y-m-d

Comment: The code that I provided in my answer will convert an MS Excel timestamp like 34398 into a unix timestamp or a PHP DateTime object; then you can use standard PHP date/time functions to format it however you want to format it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52564/discussion-between-azhar-and-mark-baker)

Answer (score 2):

The value store in PHPExcel is an Excel serialized datetime value (a float, representing the number of days since 1/1/1900 or 1/1/9004 depending on whether Windows or Mac Calendar was used). You need to convert this to a Unix timestamp or a PHP DateTime object to use PHP date functions against it for setting the format

Taken directly from the PHPExcel Date handling code:

```
function ExcelToPHP($dateValue = 0, $ExcelBaseDate = 1900) {
    if ($ExcelBaseDate == 1900) {
        $myExcelBaseDate = 25569;
        //    Adjust for the spurious 29-Feb-1900 (Day 60)
        if ($dateValue < 60) {
            --$myExcelBaseDate;
        }
    } else {
        $myExcelBaseDate = 24107;
    }

    // Perform conversion
    if ($dateValue >= 1) {
        $utcDays = $dateValue - $myExcelBaseDate;
        $returnValue = round($utcDays * 86400);
        if (($returnValue <= PHP_INT_MAX) && ($returnValue >= -PHP_INT_MAX)) {
            $returnValue = (integer) $returnValue;
        }
    } else {
        $hours = round($dateValue * 24);
        $mins = round($dateValue * 1440) - round($hours * 60);
        $secs = round($dateValue * 86400) - round($hours * 3600) - round($mins * 60);
        $returnValue = (integer) gmmktime($hours, $mins, $secs);
    }

    // Return
    return $returnValue;
}    //    function ExcelToPHP()
```

Set $ExcelBaseDate to 1900 or 1904 as necessary to indicate the Excel base calendar that you're using: Windows 1900 or Mac 1904

and if you want a PHP DateTime object instead:

```
function ExcelToPHPObject($dateValue = 0) {
    $dateTime = ExcelToPHP($dateValue);
    $days = floor($dateTime / 86400);
    $time = round((($dateTime / 86400) - $days) * 86400);
    $hours = round($time / 3600);
    $minutes = round($time / 60) - ($hours * 60);
    $seconds = round($time) - ($hours * 3600) - ($minutes * 60);

    $dateObj = date_create('1-Jan-1970+'.$days.' days');
    $dateObj->setTime($hours,$minutes,$seconds);

    return $dateObj;
}    //    function ExcelToPHPObject()
```

Comment: is $ExcelBaseDate is the Excel serialized datetime value?

Comment: No, the `$dateValue` argument is your Excel serialized timestamp (34394); the `$ExcelBaseDate` identifies which calendar MS Excel is using, which can be either the Windows 1900 calendar (base date is 1st January 1900) or the Mac 1904 calendar (base date is 1st January 1904).... in your case, if 34394 is the 1st March 1994, your using the Windows 1900 calendar which is the more common; so you don't need to pass any `$ExcelBaseDate` argument as it will default to the Windows 1900 calendar

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $cell);
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: it changed the format but after convertion the dates are different

Answer (score 0):

You can skip doing this, and ask MySQL to read whatever date format you have to its own DateTime type. Use `STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%d/%m/%Y')` in MySQL and optionally change the last argument to fit your needs... The last argument tells MySQL in what format to expect the date string.